# Can we use PDO transactions like this to ensure external API call only runs once?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I needed to make sure an External API call (which might take 200-300ms to respond) does not run more than once (Please see my Edit for a better explanation of what I'm trying to do).

This is what I finally thought of:

```
try{
    // Start Transaction
    $db->beginTransaction();

        // UPDATE (This sets in database that API call was successful)
        // Yes, before even calling the API
        $stmt = $db->prepare("QUERY1");
        $stmt->execute();

        // Row isn't updated?
        if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1){
            // STOP, It might be running in another code execution (Which is what we're trying to prevent here)
            throw new PDOException('Not updated!');
        }

        // Some External API call
        $call = $external_api->action();

        // External API call was "NOT" Successful?
        if ($call !== TRUE){
            throw new PDOException('API Failed!');
        }

        // UPDATE the same row again with "Real" API response data
        $stmt = $db->prepare("QUERY2");
        $stmt->execute();

    // All good
    $db->commit();
}catch(PDOException $e){
    // If Something went wrong rollback!
    $db->rollBack();
}
```

But I have 3 questions which I don't know the answer for:

1. Is this a good approach? or it might cause more harm than good?
2. What happens if PHP gets timed out and we don't roll back? will it roll back automatically if we don't commit?
3. In the following part of code:

   ```
   // Row isn't updated?
   if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1){
       // STOP, It might be running in another code execution (Which is what we're trying to prevent here)
       throw new PDOException('Not updated!');
   }
   ```

   If the rowCount is 0, it won't roll back anything right? (I don't want it to roll back the same Query for another Code Execution)

---

In the end, if there is a better method or approach in my case to prevent double executions, please kindly let me know.

#### Edit:

What I'm trying to do here, is stopping people from running this page from 2 different browsers at the same time (or refreshing too quickly) and getting the external api call inside this page executed more than once.

```
https://example.com/?execute_id=15
```

So if it goes inside `if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1){...}` it means this row is already updated by another execution, and by throwing execption it stops calling the following API call again.

I dunno how to explain it better :(

Comment: I'm not understanding the logic how transactions would help an API call not be executed more than once.

Comment: I dont think you understand thread logic; `if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1){` is only checked if `$stmt->execute()` is finished executing. If it fails, timeout or something else it will throw a PDOException and the rest is never executed.

Comment: @Mike Because of transaction I can update database that API Call was successful even before calling the API (and be sure it's rolled back if something goes wrong) , also the part  `if($stmt->rowCount() < 1){...}` check's if another code execution already updated that row and it will stop. this will ensure this execution is the only execution, won't it? if you have better suggestions to ensure executing the call only once (without using database or anything) please let me know.

Comment: @Xorifelse My friend I know that, that check is there to be sure that row is not already UPDATEd by another execution of code, and Yes I want it to stop the rest of the code if nothing is updated! What I'm trying to stop here is people refreshing a page too quickly and getting this external api call inside the page executed more than once.

Comment: While now I'm beginning to understand what you mean, how about just cashing the results with a short `ttl`, if expired only then make a new API call. I think you're over-complicating things.

Comment: @Xorifelse Will caching work if the External API takes 200-500ms to respond? (maybe even more?) I mean, won't it cache "After" the call is finished?

Comment: Just because a user refreshes the page, doesn't mean the server wont finish the job eventually. The only check you need to have is make sure the API call can only be made while its not running. This can be done on a per user basis by using sessions or on a global basis by storing an external var somewhere in db or file. While updating, load from cache, when finished updating write to cache.

Comment: @Xorifelse This is an external payment (financial) API, therefore I don't want to finish the job eventually, I need the API to run once. I'm doing exactly what you said: `"on a global basis by storing an external var somewhere in db"` and I'm asking if I did it correct to make sure it runs once :D anyway, Stackoverflow is asking me do not comment more, so thank you very much for trying to help, but it's not answering any of my questions :(